# Supabase: Confirm-Signup-Email always redirects to Root

Tags: javascript, supabase

I'm building a course on Supabase for my students. In the course they work in different chapters (nested folders) in a GitHub repo which they can upload on a server or test locally.

There will be a chapter (folder) for magiclink-signup and one for password-signup.

The problem is, the URL in the confirm-signup-email always redirects to the root (e.g. `https://studentserver.com`) of the server instead of `https://studentserver.ch/03\_supabase\_authentication/1\_magiclink.html`. On the root, authentication obviously fails.

I defined the redirect URL in the Supabase dashboard to my nested folder: `https://studentserver.ch/03\_supabase\_authentication/1\_magiclink.html`

And I also set the redirect-url programmatically to `window.location.href`:

```
const supa = supabase.createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, {  
 auth: {  
 redirectTo: window.location.href,
},  
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you have set as the redirect URL and what is passed to the `redirectTo` option in your sign up code has to match exactly. No extra slashes or anything are allowed. If you use `window.location.href`, it might include some slashes or extra query parameters. Because of this, it's probably better to hard code it.

Also, using underscores in your URL could cause some unwanted issues. I would rename your `html` file with hyphens instead of underscores.

[https://studiohawk.com.au/blog/dash-or-underscore-in-url-heres-how-its-affecting-your-seo/#:~:text=Underscores%20can't%20be%20used,underscore%20character%20isn't%20permitted.&text=Google's%20web%20crawlers%20don't,your%20file%20names%20for%20you](https://studiohawk.com.au/blog/dash-or-underscore-in-url-heres-how-its-affecting-your-seo/#:%7E:text=Underscores%20can%27t%20be%20used,underscore%20character%20isn%27t%20permitted.&text=Google%27s%20web%20crawlers%20don%27t,your%20file%20names%20for%20you).